# Overflow issue when screen get smaller

Tags: overflow, center

I'm using the following CSS codes to make a div center of the screen.

```
center {
top:50%;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width:30em;
height:18em;
margin-top: -9em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your height*/
margin-left: -15em; /*set to a negative number 1/2 of your width*/
border: 1px solid #ccc;
background-color: #f3f3f3;
position:absolute;
overflow: auto;
display: block;
```

}

But the problem is, when I resize the screen and when the screen getting smaller than the above mentioned div, some part of the div is disappearing. I have set the overflow option to auto, still I'm facing the problem. I need the scroll bars when screen is smaller than the div.

Please help fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add This CSS to center:

```
center{
....
    min-width: 700px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added this CSS, but still seems no difference